# Compute values frequency in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df with this settings

```
col1 col2
v1   i1
v1   i50
v2   i60
v2   i1
v2   i8 
v10  i8
v10  i1 
v10  i2 
..
```

I would like to compute how many elments of col1 has a value of col2. And store the results into a dataframe with this setting

```
col1 frequency
i1   80
i2   195
...  ...
```

I tried to do this in pandas,

```
 item_frequency = pd.unique(relevant_data[relevant_data['col2'].isin(pd.unique(relevant_data['col2'].values.ravel()))]['col1'].values.ravel())
```

which is yielding the error

```
raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

PS: I'd like to do this in a vectorized manner.

Comment: Could you clarify your task, with exact small-size input and result you want to get from this input?

Comment: so result should be col1, col2, frequency?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your statement, are you counting purely item frequency or item frequency per transaction?

Comment: @RomanPekar, actually item is unique per transaction, is it's irrelevant to put the col1 information.

Comment: @EdChum I have transactions (col1) and items (col2) and I would like to compute how many transactions have an item

Comment: @RomanPekar I was wrong in the earlier description, I  have transactions (col1) and items (col2) and I would like to compute how many transactions have an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what result you want to get, so if you want to `col1, col2, frequency` - then you can use [`groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html):

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
Out[5]: 
col1  col2
v1    i1      1
      i50     1
v10   i1      1
      i2      1
      i8      1
v2    i1      1
      i60     1
      i8      1
```

If you want just calculate count of `col2`, then [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) will work:

```
In [6]: df['col2'].value_counts()
Out[6]: 
i1     3
i8     2
i60    1
i2     1
i50    1
dtype: int64
```

**update**

After you updated your description, I see that `value_counts()` could give you wrong answer if it's possible to have one value more than once per transasction. But you can solve this with `drop_duplicates()`:

```
In [9]: df.drop_duplicates()['col2'].value_counts()
Out[9]: 
i1     3
i8     2
i60    1
i2     1
i50    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I need to compute the df[col1 where  col2 = some value].values_counts()

Comment: see updated, I think that this will give you desired answer

Comment: The requirement isn't easy to wrap once mind around, so sorry If I am not being clear. The data doesn't have duplicates when keying by (col1,col2) so no need for drop_duplicates().

Comment: Actually you are right, I did compute df['col2'].value_counts() before, but it gave me number of item occurence more than the number of transactions, which is wrong. I based my analysis on the fact that there were no duplicates, that were I went wrong, thanks